# How do I validate if the number is in proper format with respect to the locale while using Intl.numberFormat in java script?

Tags: javascript, validation, internationalization, number-formatting

I'm using Intl.numberFormat, And not able to check if the number entered by the user is in proper format for that locale, like comma separated, dot separated and space separated for some countries.

Comment: Use Regex Equation to validate.

Comment: The "locale" specifier is actually a language code, not a country. The use of "locale" in the specification is a misnomer. Just because someone is in a particular place (locale) doesn't mean they wish to use a particular format that might be associated with that locality or the language typically spoken there. Far better to use common, well known formats and tell the user what format you expect.

Comment: @RamshaSaeed—I think the OP is asking how to tell what format a user will use, they haven't gotten to the implementation part yet.

Comment: After the user selects a lang code like "de-DE" I wanted to make sure all the numbers that the user enters is validated with respect to that locale, Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the user's 'preferred' language using `window.navigator.language`, then figure out the decimal and thousand separator of that language, this example has a regular expression that accepts the thousand and decimal separators, if they're found, while keeping them optional.

```
function isValidNumber(value) {
  const locale = window.navigator.language;
  const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
  const decimalSeparator = numberFormat.format(0.1).substr(1,1);
  const thousandSeparator = numberFormat.format(1000).substr(1,1);
  const regex = new RegExp(`^\\d{1,3}(\\${thousandSeparator}\\d{3})*(\\${decimalSeparator}\\d+)?|^\\d+(\\${decimalSeparator}\\d+)?$`);
  return regex.test(value);
}
```

However, you could parameterise the locale, too - then call `isValidNumber` with `window.navigator.language` and a more standard default e.g. `en-US` and accept either format, as tolerant code makes for a better user-experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
const number = 520.25;
const locale = "en-US";

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
const formattedNumber = formatter.format(number);

const isValid = formattedNumber === formatter.format(Number(formattedNumber));

if (isValid) {
  console.log("This number is valid for 'en-US' locale.");
} else {
  console.log("This number is not valid for 'en-US' locale.");
}
```